# AWS EFS files gone without delete and efs still shows size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a multizone EFS which shows that it stores 180mb data in the AWS console.

When Accessing this efs from my beanstalk environment it is just empty desptite it had files in the past and redeploys were also working.

Now suddenly the files dont show but it still says 180mb storage is used.
I was following this guide on how to setup efs: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/main/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config

Now my efs is just empty and i dont know how.

It is not publicly available.

**EDIT**

```
$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        507M     0  507M   0% /dev
tmpfs           515M     0  515M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           515M   59M  457M  12% /run
tmpfs           515M     0  515M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.6G  3.9G  4.8G  45% /
127.0.0.1:/     9.3E     0  9.3E   0% /efs <- (AWS shows that EFS is 500mb in size)
tmpfs           103M     0  103M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I have tried to restore multiple backups but each backup is only increasing the EFS size but the files are still missing.

**EDIT2**

```
mount | grep nfs
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
127.0.0.1:/ on /efs type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,noresvport,proto=tcp,port=20644,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=127.0.0.1,local_lock=none,addr=127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: It sounds like the EFS volume is no longer mounted on your ElasticBeanstalk server, so when you go into that folder it's just going to be an empty folder on the server now. You need to mount the volume again.

Comment: The efs is mounted and I can cd into it. When I now upload files to my app it works but it seems that all the previous file are just gone and I dont know how.

Comment: If you cd into the folder where the volume should be mounted, and there are no files there, then it isn't actually mounted. In Linux you will have an empty folder if a volume gets unmounted. At that point, if you write any files to that folder they get written to the local file system instead of the network EFS file system.

Comment: It is mounted but shows 0% usage: `127.0.0.1:/     9.3E     0  9.3E   0% /efs`. I have also restored multiple backups for this efs but it has no effect the files stay the same.

Comment: You've got a different EFS volume mounted or something.

Comment: How can I check what efs is mounted?

Comment: Possibly `mount | grep nfs` or `nfsstat --mounts`. Also are you using an EFS Access Point? And if so did you perhaps modify the mount path on the access point?

Comment: I have added my output to the question. It only shows localhost.